# Are SQL Server computed primary key columns supported in Entity Framework 4? Exception thrown when inserting record

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-4

Are Sql Server computed primary key columns supported when inserting/updating records with Entity Framework 4.0? I know [they're not in Linq to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-represent-computed-columns).

Every time I try to insert a record that has a computed primary key column defined in Sql Server, I get the error

> "Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. "

even when the key's StoreGeneratedPattern property is set to Identity or Computed.

Example Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
[B1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[L1] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[L2] [varchar](5) NULL,
[E1] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
[D1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[R1] [varchar](max) NULL,
[Z1] [varchar](5) NULL,
[D2] [varchar](5) NULL,
[Key]  AS (([E1]+[B1])+[L1]),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Example edmx :

[EDMX with Key properties displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsSYw.png)

I would've just set up a normal auto-increment ID column in the database, but I've inherited this project and have been told to leave the database structure alone.